# Processing 3 / PApplet surface.setSize within Java

Tags: java, processing

I am updating some old script to P3, there is a part where I want to scale the app window to a loaded image size.

As I am working in IntelliJ and so direct in Java I can not directly access surface. Anybody knows how I can call `surface.setSize()` in a Java Project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can still get to the `surface` variable. Just call the `getSurface()` function of the `PApplet` class. If you're extending `PApplet`, you can just call it directly.

```
public class MySketch extends PApplet{

   public void mousePressed(){
      getSurface().setSize(200, 200);
   }

   // other functions

}
```

Also note that if you're loading the image at the beginning, you can just use the `settings()` function and call `size()` instead of going through the `surface` variable.